# Require paths not working using google api php library

Tags: php, require, google-api-php-client

My problem is the next one,

I tried to integrate the google login using OAuth 2.0 feature into my company backend.

I tested it on my domain , www.gabrielestevez.com, everything here works perfect, there is no problem with the require paths, everything runs smothly

But , the company backend directories has the following structure
[image]

I'm using a mvc framework developed by me , the Google_SL.php file contains the class where I make the first two require_once

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Oauth2.php';
```

which works fine, but then when it goes to the client.php and is trying to load this class

```
require_once 'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php';
```

is not working , this is the error
An error occurred in script '/home/xxx/public_html/admin/hmf/Core/library/auth/Google/Client.php' on line 18: require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Date/Time: 9-19-2014 11:50:29

, I don't want to change manually all the path within this library because I know there is got to be a better solution to this

any input is appreciated.

Comment: The issue is that you're using relative paths, obviously. The only solution to this is to change how the files are included, you could use an auto-loader, I guess, or you could just do it the right way(IMO) and define a base path, then concatenate the inclusion path from there.

Comment: could you explain a little bit or point me to a link where I can check this, I've always struggle a little bit with relatives path

Comment: by the way , what is IMO?

Comment: IMO == in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for future reference

I fixed my issue using this 
set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/hmf/Core/library/auth/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

Answer (score 0):

Try use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to get the current directory of the script. Not exactly sure where your `AssertionCredentials.php` is, but try something like

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php');
```

Comment: This is what I don't want to do, I would have to do this for all the files and is very time consuming

Comment: I thought you only need to change client.php? So your AssertionCredentials.php is required in multiple places? Hopefully, this only affects a small subest of your application.